# Rails can't find webpacked files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I keep trying to follow the various "How to create a react/rails app" guides but for some reason my rails server is never able to find my packed files

I create the app with this: rails *5.2.3* new appname -d=postgresql --webpack=react --skip-coffee

I then create a basic static_pages_controller, root to that controller in my routes, and create a view with just <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>

But when I run webpacker and start up the rails server, I keep getting the same error: Rack app error handling request { GET /packs/js/application-19535d76806286f61e2d.js }